# How to make child collide

Tags: game-engine

I want to make a tree which is made of segments connected via parenting, i want the children have collision with the environment, atm the children will simply pass throught them.

How can i make it.

edit: described what i want in image
[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking,but check this :
[rigid body constraint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEKx24Pjihc)
The bad thing is I don't know how to solve your questions if this is what you are looking.

Comment: i need segments to stand still, i want to make if the bottom of segment gets unparented, it and the children would fall(like realisistic tree), but the only bottom segment has collision, not the children. Need parent and children have collision to the environment

Comment: Maybe try the remove parent actuator and make the leaves dynamic so gravity will pull them down.

Comment: the best would if the rest to up would fall connected to the lowest segment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this answer in Mike Pan's and Dalai Felinto's marvellous book *Game Development in blender* (cengage learning, 2014). I will re-word it to avoid any copyright infringement.

[image]

This can be solved with the *Compound* option for collision bounds.
Make sure all the objects you have are collision bound enabled and then check the "Compound" box, described as "Add children to form a compound collision object". If you check this option on not only the parent, but *all the children as well* you get a parent object that dynamically adds the children to the parents collision bounds.

[image]

young parents, remember this as a way to control your children.

Comment: @terrio, does this answer your question?

Comment: yes it does thx